# PHP Classes:: Why declare as a new?

Tags: php, function, class, variables, object

I'm very new to php classes and I was wonder why do I need to declare it to a variable and set it as NEW?

Here is an example :

```
class myFirstClass {
    function Version(){
        return 'Version 1';
    }
    function Info(){
        return 'This class is doing nothing';
    }
}

$hola = new myFirstClass;

echo $hola->Version();
```

Why this won't work WITHOUT declare it to a variable and set it to NEW ?

In other words... Without this line :

```
$hola = new myFirstClass;
```

I'm so used to functions so it looks weird to me...

Comment: you have to create an instance. that is why `new` is used.

Comment: Because this is how OOP works.  You need to make a "new" instance of an `myFirstClass` object.

Comment: You have to read in more in OOP, that's how it works! You can imagine the class as a plan and with new you create an exact copy from this plan an build an object! Then plan you can't use, but if you have made your object you can use this!

Comment: I can say that function is a plan and I'm passing new variables to that function and create a very new results that made from scratch and I can treat it as the same (or almost the same) as I use classes. So why function don't need that kind of declaration ?

Comment: Which `kind of declaration`? Do you mean the modifiers `public`, `private` and so on ?

Comment: Don't think of classes as function collections. They're just outlines to apply behaviour to data collections. Objects are simply actors which know something and do something; and get created from class descriptions. Unless you have at least two objects (possibly from different class schemes) that know how to communicate based on contained knowledge/variables, it's not useful by itself. If you only want to mangle data in→out, then use plain functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right! It is not necessary to use the `new` operator:

```
class myFirstClass {
    static function Version(){// static keyword
        return 'Version 1';
    }
    function Info(){
        return 'This class is doing nothing';
    }
}

echo myFirstClass::Version();// direct call
```

Comment: ...if you are accessing a static method.  It all depends what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

This is a basic principle of Object Oriented Programming (OOP). Let's use a library system for example. If you want to get the name of a book, you cannot just say "give me the name of the book", you have to know what book (by id, author, whatever).

In functions, you can write one that looks like this:

```
function get_book($id){ // code }
```

In OOP it doesn't really work that way. You have a class book that keeps a name. But that name is only for that given book.

```
class Book {
  var $name;
  public __construct($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
  }

  public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
  }
}
```

In order to call the `getName()` function we need to have a book. This is what new does.

```
$book = new Book("my title");
```

Now if we use the `getName()` function on `$book` we'll get the title.

```
$book->getName(); // returns "my title"
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

To create an instance of a class, the new keyword must be used. An object will always be created unless the object has a constructor defined that throws an exception on error. Classes should be defined before instantiation (and in some cases this is a requirement).

If a string containing the name of a class is used with new, a new instance of that class will be created. If the class is in a namespace, its fully qualified name must be used when doing this.

> The Basics

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

> Classes and Objects

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 1):

This line:

`$hola = new myFirstClass;`

Is saying:  create a new object called `$hola`, then put a new instance of `myFirstClass` into `$hola`. Now `$hola` is literally a object containing a new instance of `myFirstClass`.

Comment: I got it but still... I don't understand why do I need to pass it to a variable and can't use it as function like for example : echo myFirstClass->Version();

Comment: It's a way to reference the object, that's all! You would call $hola.someMethod(); to use a method from it.